# Django Using multiple (two) user types extending AbstractUser

Tags: python, django, database, model

**UPDATE**: The fix has been found. The problem has been laying in the Models.py, where we are trying to save donor/hospital as a User instance, but we did not use self.donor (we used donor and assumed it will be related to the created instance).

For our project, we have two user types: Donor and Hospital. So we use the User model, which extends the AbstractUser model. The Donor and Hospital models both have OneToOneField relationship with the User and it uses the default user authentication.

Almost everything works fine. The Donor and Hospital creation works well, the instances are added to the database and we can log in.

However, we need the Donor object and its fields in the view and in the template. We have the user contained in the request and the id of the user.

`donor = Donor.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)`

Or

`donor = Donor.objects.filter(donor=request.user).first()`

Should return the donor object, but it returns None.

It works for Hospital.

If we do Donor.objects.all() the newly created Donor is not in the list. However, created hospital is present in the list.

We cannot figure out what is the problem, the ids for donor and user do not match.

Thank you very much for your help!

These are our models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_donor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_hospital = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Donor(models.Model):
    # username, pword, first+last name, email
    donor = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

    # donor_id = models.IntegerField(auto_created=True, unique=True, null=False, primary_key=True)

    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    blood_type = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    weight = models.IntegerField()
    height = models.IntegerField()
    birth = models.DateField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    notification = models.BooleanField
    likedStories = models.TextField(default=json.dumps([]))

    def get_age(self, b):
        return int((datetime.date.today() - datetime.datetime.strptime(b, "%Y-%m-%d").date()).days / 365.25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.donor.username

    def new_donor(self, data):

        try:
            MISTAKE # donor = User.objects.create_user(username=data['email'], password=data['password'])
            self.donor = User.objects.create_user(username=data['email'], password=data['password'])
        except IntegrityError:
            return {'error': "email already exists"}
        except:
            return {'error': "something went wrong with email please try again"}

        donor.first_name = data['first_name']
        donor.last_name = data['last_name']
        # donor.nickname = data['nickname']
        donor.is_donor = True

        self.nickname = data['username']
        self.birth = (data['birthday'])
        self.age = self.get_age(self.birth)

        self.address = data['city']

        self.height = data['height']
        self.weight = data['weight']

        self.blood_type = data['blood_type']
        # self.notification = data['notification']

        try:
            # HAS TO BE SELF. THE SAME FOR HOSPITAL
            self.donor.save()
            self.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            donor.delete()
            return {'error': "nickname already exists"}
        except:
            donor.delete()
            return {'error': "something went wrong with nickname please try again"}

        return {'error': None}


class Hospital(models.Model):
    # email, pword
    hospital = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

    # hospital_id = models.IntegerField(auto_created=True, unique=True, null=False, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    notified_types = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug_name = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    # stories = models.ManyToOneRel(Hospital, )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug_name = slugify(self.name)
        super(Hospital, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def new_hospital(self, data):
        # hospital = User.objects.create_user(data['hospital_name'], data['hospital_email'], data['hospital_password'])
        hospital = User.objects.create_user(username=data['hospital_email'], password=data['hospital_password'])
        hospital.is_hospital = True
        self.name = data['hospital_name']
        self.location = data['location']
        # self.notified_types = data['notif_types']

        hospital.save()
        self.save()
```

This is the model, where I need to get the Donor field:

```
@login_required
def app(request):
    context_dict = {}
    # Get 4 most liked stories
    stories = Story.objects.order_by('-likes')[:4]

    # Get all reviews of by the donor
    reviews = Review.objects.all()

    context_dict["stories"] = stories
    context_dict["reviews"] = reviews

    print("Is donor:")
    print(request.user.is_donor)
    print("Is hospital:")
    print(request.user.is_hospital)
    print("All donors:")
    print(Donor.objects.all())
    print("All hospitals:")
    print(Hospital.objects.all())
    print("Has user blood_type attribute:")
    print(request.user._meta.fields)
    # print (Donor.objects.get(donor_id = request.user.id).nickname)
    if request.user.is_hospital:
        hospital = Hospital.objects.filter(hospital=request.user).first()
        print(hospital)
        context_dict["hospital"] = hospital
    else:
        donor = Donor.objects.filter(donor=request.user).first()
        print(donor)
        # context_dict["donor"] = donor

    response = render(request, 'app/app.html', context=context_dict)
    # Return a rendered response to send to the client.
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

```
donor = Donor.objects.get(donor__user=request.user)
```

or

```
donor = Donor.objects.get(donor__user.id=request.user.id)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives: DoesNotExist at /app/app/
Donor matching query does not exist. We have found out the problem is that the User field donor does not exist. This error: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /app/app/
User has no donor.

Comment: The id of the user is 9 but the is of the donor is 6, but it does not make sense why is it not related if the hospital is.

Comment: Thank you for your help. One of our team member eventually found the fix. The problem has been in the model as we were saving the donor or hospital, we have not used self.donor and hence the information has not been saved for the given instance.